# How to direct `M-:`'s value to the current buffer?

Tags: echo-area, eval-expression

[According to the Emacs manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Lisp-Eval.html), `M-:` evaluates an Emacs Lisp expression and prints the value in the echo area. How can I direct the value to the current buffer instead?

Comment: The contents of the echo area are generally in the `*Messages*` buffer. You can switch to that buffer using `(view-echo-area-messages)` which is bound to `C-h e` by default. From that buffer you can freely copy text.

Comment: I think the current answer is a better choice because it the question you've asked in the title and #1 & #2 in the text. My comment is really about #3, which seems like a separate question.

Comment: OK, then I think you need to split this up because you are asking three different things: How does one insert the `M-:` output in to the current buffer? Why does that not work for one specific case, `magit-version`? And totally unrelated, how does one get back to text that was shown in the echo area?

Comment: @glucas: The current answer doesn't answer questions #2 and #3. #3 was in the original post. I can't accept their answer. All three questions are answered by your comment, for all my purposes.

Comment: To make this site generally useful, it helps to have focused questions -- that way other users with similar questions can find the answers they need. Right now the question you have asked  is "How do I insert the output of `M-:` in to the current buffer", which has already been answered. If the question you really intended to ask was "How can I copy the message echoed by `magit-version`" then please change the question, because that answer would have nothing to do with `M-:` at all.

Comment: @glucas: I will revert the post to its original form and change the title correspondingly. Unfortunately, it still means I can't accept the current answer, since it doesn't address one of the two questions asked.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56548/discussion-between-glucas-and-evan-aad).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use `C-u M-:` insert the result into current buffer instead of printing it in the echo area.

> (eval-expression EXP &optional INSERT-VALUE)
>
> Evaluate EXP and print value in the echo area.
> When called interactively, read an Emacs Lisp expression and evaluate it.
> Value is also consed on to front of the variable ‘values’.
> If the resulting value is an integer, it will be printed in
> several additional formats (octal, hexadecimal, and character).
> Optional argument INSERT-VALUE non-nil (interactively, with
> prefix argument) means insert the result into the current buffer
> instead of printing it in the echo area.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I tried to follow your advice and evaluated `C-u M-x magit-version RET` while in the `*sctach*` buffer, but the output wrote to the echo area rather than `*scratch*`.

Comment: ```C-u M-: (magit-version) <RET>```

Comment: `C-u M-x (magit-version) RET` prints `[No match]` to the minibuffer.

Comment: sorry about, there a typo: ```C-u M-: (magit-version) <RET>```

Comment: `C-u M-: (magit-version) RET` works, but it doesn't print the same output as `M-x magit-version RET`, for instance the Git version is not printed. Is there a way to direct the complete output of the `M-x` version to the current buffer?

Comment: ```M-x magit-version``` eval ```command``` version, ```M-: (magit-version)``` eval ```variable``` version

Comment: Is there a way, then, to direct the output of the *command* `M-x magit-version RET` to the current buffer?

Comment: The `magit-version` command returns as a result only the version number, so that is what you can insert in to the buffer. If you look at the source for `magit-version` you'll find that the additional information is displayed via the  `(message ....)` function -- so if you want that text you would need to temporarily advise / override `message`.

Comment: What @glucas said. Or just pick up some of the code that prints that info in `*Messages*` (or similar) and use it to print the info wherever else you want.

Comment: do it yourself:
```
(defun self-magit-version ()
  (require 'magit)
  (format "Magit %s, Git %s, Emacs %s, %s"
          (or magit-version "(unknown)")
          (or (magit-git-version t) "(unknown)")
          emacs-version
          system-type))
```